# Angular : Determining the count of the properties that contain value in array of objects

Tags: angular

I have AllTerms which is an array objects and each object has two properties called `LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel` and `LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel`.

I need to know the length of total properties. For some objects the LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel would be null hence would not be counted. How do I determine the count or length.

this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel contains the AllTerms object.

```
this.LegalFundClasses = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel
```

JSON

```
[{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11166,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11167,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":13713,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":19,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"BRL","OtherCurrencyName":[10,19,7],"ManagerStrategyId":5508,"ManagerStrategyName":"Sylebra ","SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":2,"HardDurationMonthsName":"3","SoftDurationMonthsId":3,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"6","LockupFees0To12Pct":2,"LockupFees12To24Pct":2,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":true,"GateInvestorPct":3,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":3,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":1,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Business","ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":true,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":"test","PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 10, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":28465,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":7,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"AUD","OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":5508,"ManagerStrategyName":"Sylebra ","SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":2,"RedsFrqncyName":"Weekly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":2,"HardDurationMonthsName":"3","SoftDurationMonthsId":3,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"6","LockupFees0To12Pct":2,"LockupFees12To24Pct":2,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":true,"GateInvestorPct":3,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":3,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":1,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Business","ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":"test","PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":13713}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":" ","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13714,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28485,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":13714}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13715,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B1","AuditSummary":"wfilipek Jun 06, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13716,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":22,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"72","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13717,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"test45454","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 10, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28466,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"test45454","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28490,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":28466}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"RanjitA","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28486,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":null,"RedsFrqncyName":null,"RedsNoticeDays":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":null,"LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":null,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the number of each key where the value of the prop is not null, for top-level keys in that array.

For each of these, you need to iterate the properties. Something like this works?

*Edit: updated answer as per OP's comment.*

```js
/**
 * let's reduce the array and pick up props from each of the entries that is not null.
 */
function countProps(array) {
 const props = array.reduce((result, entry) => {
     const props = Object.entries(entry); // now we have an array with [key, value] entries for each property.
     for (const [key, val] of props) {
         if (val !== null) {
          // if the value is not null, add it. 
             result[key] = result[key] ? result[key] + 1 : 1;
         }
     }
     return result;
 }, {});
  const totalCountOfProps = Object.keys(props).reduce((total, entry) => total + props[entry], 0);
  return totalCountOfProps; 
}

const testArray = [ { one: 'two' }, { two: null }, { one: 1, two: 2 }, { one: null, three: 0 } ];
console.log(countProps(testArray));

// let us try with your array
const yourArray = [{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11166,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"skeeling Jun 11, 2018","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":11167,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.03|","LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":13713,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":19,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"BRL","OtherCurrencyName":[10,19,7],"ManagerStrategyId":5508,"ManagerStrategyName":"Sylebra ","SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":2,"HardDurationMonthsName":"3","SoftDurationMonthsId":3,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"6","LockupFees0To12Pct":2,"LockupFees12To24Pct":2,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":true,"GateInvestorPct":3,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":3,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":1,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Business","ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":true,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":"test","PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"Class A","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 10, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji May 28, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"kweigand Jan 16, 2019","Id":28465,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":7,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"AUD","OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":5508,"ManagerStrategyName":"Sylebra ","SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":2,"RedsFrqncyName":"Weekly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":2,"HardDurationMonthsName":"3","SoftDurationMonthsId":3,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"6","LockupFees0To12Pct":2,"LockupFees12To24Pct":2,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":true,"GateInvestorPct":3,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":3,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":1,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Business","ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":"test","PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":13713}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":" ","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13714,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"Class D","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28485,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":13714}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C","AuditSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13715,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B1","AuditSummary":"wfilipek Jun 06, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"kweigand Feb 19, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"fblack Nov 21, 2018","Id":13716,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":22,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"72","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":13717,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":46,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":5,"LockupTypeName":"No Lock","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"In the SOT, there is a 1-year lock, this is no longer applicable and was only applicable for the original transfer from Sylebra commingled.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":0,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":30,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":2,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","HoldbackPercentage":0,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":0,"IncentiveFeeRate":30,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":0,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":1,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":"Management Fee","FeeComments":"New fees effective 1/1/2019 \n\nManagement fee is an Asset Based fee of the lesser of $1M or 1.5% of NAV.  This is a payment in advance of any performance fee, making the management fee effectively zero.\n\nIncentive fee is 30% on first 15% of performance, 35% thereafter.\n\nAudit holdbacks should be zero unless the vehicle is in liquidation, in which case it's typically a 5% holdback paid once the audit is completed where applicable or 2-3 months after the final NAV once all the expenses have been paid.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"test45454","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 10, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28466,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":{"Description":"test45454","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28490,"FundId":5508,"FundClassType":4,"CurrencyId":null,"PrimaryCurrencyName":null,"OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":5,"RedsFrqncyName":"Quarterly","RedsNoticeDays":45,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":3,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":0,"LegalParentClassId":28466}},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"RanjitA","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","Id":28486,"FundId":237146,"FundClassType":3,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyName":[],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":null,"SubVotingName":null,"SubHotIssueId":null,"SubHotIssueName":null,"RedsFrqncyId":null,"RedsFrqncyName":null,"RedsNoticeDays":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":null,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":null,"LockupTypeId":null,"LockupTypeName":null,"HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":null,"SoftDurationMonthsName":null,"LockupFees0To12Pct":null,"LockupFees12To24Pct":null,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":null,"ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":null,"GateSourceId":null,"GateSourceName":null,"GateFundClassPct":null,"IntialProceeds":null,"PaymentInDays":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":null,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":null,"HoldbackPercentage":null,"HoldbackPayment":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":null,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":null,"ManagementFeeRate":null,"IncentiveFeeRate":null,"RealizationFrequencyId":null,"RealizationFrequencyName":null,"HighWaterMarkId":null,"HighWaterMarkName":null,"HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":null,"FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":null,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null}]
;

console.log(countProps(yourArray));
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. Preferred if the function returned just the number 12 in this case

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array of objects and convert objects into `keys`. Keys are your properties and returned as array. `length` of each keys are your count. You can use if condition to ignore if object is null or does not have specific property.

```js
const profiles = [{
    name: 'Ma',
    age: 21,
    gender: 'male'
  }, {
    name: 'Ma',
    age: null,
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {}
];

profiles.map(p => {
  console.log(Object.keys(p).length)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const a =  [
  {
    "LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel": {
      "Description": "Class B",
      "AuditSummary": "skeeling Jun 11, 2018",
      "FeesReviewSummary": "",
      "RealizationFrequencyId": null,
      "GpCatchUp": null,
      "PreferredReturnComments": null,
      "Clawback": false,
      "ClawbackPercentage": null,
      "AssetFeeDiscountTypeId": null,
      "AssetFeeDiscountTypeName": null,
      "FeeComments": null,
      "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
      "InvestmentStatusId": 0,
      "LegalParentClassId": null
    },
    "LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel": null
  },
  {
    "LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel": {
      "Description": "Class A",
      "AuditSummary": "skeeling Jun 11, 2018",
      "FeesReviewSummary": "",
      "TermsReviewSummary": "",
      "Id": 11167,
      "GateInvestorPct": null,
      "GateSourceId": null,
      "GateSourceName": null,
      "FeeComments": null,
      "FeeReductionsNegotiated": null,
      "InvestmentStatusId": 0,
      "LegalParentClassId": null
    },
    "LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel": null
  }
]

const result = a.map(res=>Object.entries(res).map(([key, value])=>(value && 1 || 0))).reduce((a,e)=>a+e[0]+e[1],0);

console.log(result) // return 2
```

Comment: Hi, I am not looking at counting the number of fields here. LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel will always be having the same number for fields. As per your data it should return LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel is 2 and LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel is none so the record count is 2

Comment: @Tom , I fix it